# Read YAML in phantom js replacing value with that from bash script

Tags: bash, phantomjs

Have a static `yaml` file. Where I am running some testing in phantom js driver. I have defined two URL, one is for **staging** version and another is for **production** version.
YAML file looks like

```
browser:
  chromejs: "phantomjs"
# we've deliberately left out the snap_file
resize_or_reload: 'reload'  
# Type the name of the directory that shots will be stored in
directory: 'compare/alohavillas'
#before snap
before_capture: 'templates/javascript/wait--phantom.js'
# Add only 2 domains, key will act as a label
domains:
  Production: "https://www.google.com"
  Staging: "https://www.staging-google.com" # i want to make this like dynamic
```

problem is, I want to take dynamic value staging site address from a bash file

**Stagingurl.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
urlvalue="https://www.staging-google.com"
echo $urlvalue
```

How can I read value from bash file?

Comment: You want to read from `yaml` the value of a variable from `bash` file? But `yaml` is just a text file, it's static, not an "actor"/"program" that can "do things" like "read".

Comment: There is nothing in YAML that allows you to do that, it is not in specification. The program that loads the YAML file, might implement something that updates the datastructure loaded from YAML by parsing the bash script and pantom js (phantom js?) might do that for you.

Comment: Thanks for your information